# Clustering evaluation metric when overclustering is of

Tags: clustering, accuracy, model-evaluation, mutual-information

What evaluation metric should be used to measure clustering performance when over-clustering is OK as long as it happens only within ground truth clusters, with no confusion of ground truth clusters.

For example if the ground truth look like:

`labels = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

The following clustering is fine because the prediction is not confusing the ground truth clusters:
`preds = [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 4]`

But the following should be penalized:
`preds= [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

Because the 2 middle samples predicted to be in one cluster actually belong to 2 different clusters in ground truth.

Note that the absolute value of the labels and predictions does not matter in my examples.

I have looked into accuracy and mutual information based measures, none of these are suitable for what I am trying to measure. Accuracy will penalize any over-clustering because the labels won't match, and mutual information will be affected by over-clustering because it increases the entropy of predictions.

Comment: I think cluster homogeneity is the measure I am looking for!

Comment: Have you looked at Adjusted Rand Index (ARI)? ARI does not match absolute values of labels, hence may be suitable for your purpose.

Comment: The third and the last point are in different clusters in the ground truth, but assigned to the same cluster in your first clustering. Is that not a problem?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Sorry that was a typo, I edited the question.

Comment: What is overclustering, and when is it "of"?

Comment: Also, in your reasoning, the answer 1...N with each point its own cluster would always be best, won't it?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes it would be best if I have n_clusters=N. But luckily you can specify number of clusters in some clustering methods.

Comment: Still this shows this evaluation method has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out slides 44 through 46 at the link below. I like the considerations they lead to when thinking about comparing to ground truth.

https://cse.buffalo.edu/~jing/cse601/fa12/materials/clustering_basics.pdf

The Jaccard coefficient takes into account the instances of membership in the same ground truth cluster but different calculated clusters, as well as the instances of membership in the same calculated cluster but different ground truth clusters.

Since you don’t need a penalty for those with the same ground truth cluster but different calculated clusters, modify the calculation by taking this bit out of the denominator(|DS| on the slides).

You are left with:

```
(Same ground truth cluster and same calculated cluster)

-Divided by-

((Same ground truth cluster and same calculated cluster) + (Different ground truth cluster and same calculated cluster))
```